# Finding a vector position

Tags: geometry, vectors

> "The position vectors of points $A$ and $B$ relative to the origin are
>   $3i+2j-k$ and $5i+6j+5k$ respectively. Find the position vector of the
>   point $P$ which lies on $AB$ produced such that $AP=3BP$."

Actually I can solve this, provided I find where P lies - on $AB$ line sector or the continuation of $AB$. That's exactly what I don't understand -  how to visualize the problem.

How do I figure out where exactly $P$ lies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is written that "point P which lies on AB produced", therefore P doesn't lie on line AB and given is the case of external division.

Apply the external section formula directly.

Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was it, I didn't understand the expression properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my understanding of the problem:

[image]

The point $P$ is at $A + 3/4 (B-A)$.

Comment: P lies on AB produced and not on AB as you are assuming.

Comment: What does "AB produced" mean?

Comment: Means that you have to extend AB to get P on that, it is not on line segment AB.

Comment: "AB produced" is not standard English.